# getMap and AutoComplete setCountry android

Tags: android, google-places-api, supportmapfragment, gmsplacepicker

getMap needs old gms playService 
but
setCountry("") needs new gms playservice version.
How to use both of them in the Same Application??

```
  supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);

        googleMap = supportMapFragment.getMap();

//===================================================================

    AutocompleteFilter typeFilter = new AutocompleteFilter.Builder().setCountry("EG")
            .build();

    autocompleteFragment.setFilter(typeFilter);
```

Comment: getMap() method is deprecated, so what you can do is update to newer version and use **getMapAsync()** method instead of **getMap()**.

Comment: I know that but I need to use both of getMap  and setCountry